# Facebook Like vs Google +1

Tags: interaction-design, buttons, social-media

We are thinking of implementing the like feature in our mobile app. Do not confuse it to be a social like or such, but this like will be saved on our own database within the app. Thats it!

In order to have this functionality we were thinking about Like functionality similar facebook thumps up but then we have seen a different approach being used by Google +1 (Vote Up) the posts. SE also uses a similar vote up functionality though not similar completely.

Is there any benefit or different scenarios where you would be using one over the other? My problem is that the Like is now thought of Facebook Like all the time but our app does not share the like on Facebook which may be confusing for the users.

[image] **vs** [image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the upvote in your database? Why would the user take action by upvoting? What's in it for them? Is it feedback that the content was helpful? Are they training a neural network? Thanks!

Comment: Its a web page where users will post questions during a conference session. Then each participant votes up / likes the questions. In the end the speaker can know what are the questions that are mostly liked / voted up. Then during the Q&A the speakers answers the highly liked or voted questions.

Comment: So essentially doing like Reddit? Or HackerNews? Or perhaps even like Digg so many years ago?

Comment: use some icons with outline and filled states (hearts, stars, etc). If you need to encourage users to downvote, SO-style up/down buttons.

Comment: @AyeshK Hearts was an option I was thinking as it is still not associated with the big giant social networks as such! I will A/B test with different options and see which one works the best. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: I'm confused at what the actual question is.

Comment: My question is whether to use thumbs up or +1 or upvoting questions in my scenario? I am relunctant to use the thumbs up icon as the users may expect its going to post on their fb!

Comment: There's no way anyone could give you a definite answer to that.  It's purely subjective.  I would say that if you wanted less confusion, do neither.  Create something specific to your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your comment :

> Its a web page where users will post questions during a conference
>   session. Then each participant votes up / likes the questions. In the
>   end the speaker can know what are the questions that are mostly liked
>   / voted up. Then during the Q&A the speakers answers the highly liked
>   or voted questions.

Similar to Stack Exchange comments that just allow an upvote and not a downvote I would use a **single up arrow** either outlined or greyed. Then allow this to be clickable and when done so it gets coloured. If clicked again it can go back to the neutral state.

[image]

This is a generic control that wont be confused with any other website use of an upvote/like/+1 system and also wont carry any connotations associated with these specific uses.

Comment: This is a good option. I will A/B test with different settings and see how they turn out.